# Jquery Changing CSS class of object based on numeric content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Going to be outputting percentages dynamically 0-100%

Want to add CSS class based on percentage. Red for 0% and Blue for 100% progressively.

Markup would be

```
<span class="blue">100%</span>
```

Originally I had thought something along this line....

```
$("span:contains('100%')").css("color", "#0000ff");
```

But contains only searching first integer and applying different classes for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
only problem with this method is single digit numbers would be treated the same as double. IE 7% and 70% would have the same class and wouldn't be correct.

These aren't specific amounts, they are going to dynamically change all the time. I am not very good at writing my own jquery so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Regardless of the code used to create it, what output are you expecting for values other than 0% or 100%? Let's say we have 70%: what **should** the class name look like?

Comment: Is this written in another language - PHP, ASP...etc?  Or just straight HTML?

Comment: I tried what I think you described above in jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/PPwEq/, in both Firefox 4 and IE 9, and I don't see any problem...that is, if I understood the question correctly, which I'm not sure I have...

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/GJh3j/

Contains is going to be a pretty expensive query if you have a lot of elements on the page. 
I would:

Add a class to all elements:

```
<span class="percent-holder">100%</span>
<span class="percent-holder">100%</span>
<span class="percent-holder">0%</span>
<span class="percent-holder">100%</span>
```

Find all those elements, analyze their text, do what you want:

```
$( '.percent-holder' ).each( function()
{
    var $this = $( this ),
        classToAdd = null;

    switch( $this.text() )
    {
        case '100%':
            classToAdd = 'blue';
            break;

        case '0%':
            classToAdd = 'red';
            break;
    }

    if( classToAdd !== null )
    {
        $this.addClass( classToAdd );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Why does the variable name `$this` have a **$** in front of it?

Comment: Because it's `this` after having been run through the jQuery factory ( `$( this )` ). Could be named anything. I just like that particular style.

Comment: Gotcha. Wasn't sure if it was a naming convention, or if it had any special meaning. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with using `:contains()` (see http://jsfiddle.net/b3tUf/), but if you want to change your code, you could always just use conditional statements.

```
if( $("span").text() == "0%" ) {
    $("span").css("color", "#0000ff");
} elseif ( $("span").text() == "100%" ) {
    ...
}
```

or for classes:

```
if( $("span").text() == "0%" ) {
    $("span").removeClass().addClass("red");
} elseif ( $("span").text() == "100%" ) {
    $("span").removeClass().addClass("blue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna manage the percentage colors yourself manually, you could do it like this:

```
$('span').css('color', function() {
 var percentage = parseInt($(this).text());  
    switch(percentage){
        case 100:
          return "red";
        case 90:
          return "gray";                 
    }
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/zqwqe/

edit: alternatively you could calculate the color value dynamically, so you wouldn't have to define each percentage seperately.

```
    $('<span />').appendTo($('body')).text(i+"%").css('color', function() {
        var percentage = parseInt($(this).text());  
        var colors = [Math.round(255*(percentage/100)),0,255-Math.round(255*(percentage/100))];
        return "rgb("+colors+")";   
        });
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/zqwqe/29/

Comment: If the text is `100%`, parseInt probably wouldn't do the job for you.

Comment: @Wex 100 is an integer? It seems to be working fine in the example. Could you please elaborate why it wouldn't work?

Comment: My mistake, I'm far too used to working with C++ to be jumping to conclusions like that.

Comment: @Wex I'm not denying it could be the case, I just don't see why it would do that. Isn't a string in C++ which contains "100%", when parsed to an integer, also 100?