# How do I display a negative currency in red?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following html code...

```
<%=String.Format("{0:C0}", item.currency)%>
```

I need the currency format but my negative is being displayed like this...

```
($2,345)
```

I would like the format to be in red. I can set a toggle variable, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Are you displaying that text raw on the page or inside of some HTML control?  You can set the style to red color if `item.currency < 0`.

Comment: Ok, so I have to check the currency and cannot format how I display negatives...

Comment: with jQuery you can achieve this

Comment: Changing CSS class of object based on numeric content - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284408/jquery-changing-css-class-of-object-based-on-numeric-content

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I wanted to do the same thing, but also display the negative value as "-$2345" rather than in parentheses.

To take care of the format, I first added the following to my BaseController class (which, as the name implies, is the base class for all of my Controllers):

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo modCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    modCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = modCulture;
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx. That took care of the formatting of the number.  As for the red, I added a new css class called "negative":

```
.negative
{
    color: Red;
}
```

And then in my .aspx file:

```
<% if (item.currency < 0.0M)
{ %>
<span class="negative"><%=String.Format("{0:C}", item.currency)%></span>
<% }
else
{ %>
<span><%=String.Format("{0:C}", item.currency)%></span>
<% } %>
```

The benefit of putting this in a css class is that, for dynamic sites, if it later becomes positive (or vice versa, if a positive value becomes negative), I can use jQuery to simply add or remove the class from the span/div in question and make the text default or red.

Comment: What do you refer by BaseController class ?

Comment: @Laggel I created a BaseController class from which all of my other Controllers derived.  That gave me a single place to put common setup code (like that in the Initialize I mentioned above).