# How can I show Currency with Negative instead of Parentheis in ASP NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo, negative-number

I want my values to be shown in the views

Like: -$150.00

Instead of: ($150.00)

--

I guess this is what I have to do:

[How do I display a negative currency in red?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472765/how-do-i-display-a-negative-currency-in-red)

But I don't know what does he means by "BaseController class"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So merging @Jon Skeet answer with this one

The Real Answer was to add this method to the Global.asax.cs file of your MVC Project. And that's it.

The key is the second line:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
            culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;    

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's all down to [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx). Presumably you've got the value 0, when it sounds like you want 1.

It's not clear whether you're currently using the user's `CultureInfo`, the server's one, or something else. But you could always clone whichever culture you're using, then modify the `NumberFormatInfo`.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var original = new CultureInfo("en-us");
        // Prints ($5.50)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(original, "{0:C}", -5.50m));

        var modified = (CultureInfo) original.Clone();
        modified.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;        
        // Prints -$5.50
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(modified, "{0:C}", -5.50m));
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do that? I mean in which part of my project should I place this for all of my currency formated fields to be updated?

Comment: @Laggel: I don't know enough about MVC internationalization to say, to be honest - but I've edited my answer to show you how to change a cloned culture. I know it's not everything, but it's at least a start...

Comment: Note: I'm talking about an ASP NET MVC project. Where I dont have a main method. And I dont use string.Format to format the values, there are being formatted automatically by DataAnnotations and @Html.DisplayFor

Comment: @Laggel: Yes, I know - you'll need to investigate more about MVC i18n in general, and what your specific project is doing in terms of user culture etc. (I suspect that there are various different options in terms of which culture is used.) See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx for a start (although it's a bit old now.)